# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no dbjdbc17 in java.library.path

Tags: linux, jdbc, sqlanywhere, unsatisfiedlinkerror, java.library.path

I am trying to connect a java program to a database SQL Anywhere 17 using JDBC connection SQL Anywhere 17 installed in Windows machine.  I have built a JAR to run the connection. The JAR is working in another Windows machine. I have `jconn4.jar` and `dbjdbc17.dll` files in the same directory as the JAR and running the JAR command `java -classpath connect.jar;jconn4.jar com.Main`.

When I moved the same JAR directory to a Linux machine, I'm getting this:

> exception.java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no dbjdbc17 in java.library.path.

Can we connect SQL Anywhere 17 installed in Windows from Linux machine? Can someone suggest me the correct way to run this JAR in Linux which is working in Windows?

Comment: Do you have a `libdbjdbc17.so`? If not, that is the problem. `.dll` is for Windows.

Comment: Hi @Mark Rotteveel, Thanks for responding . Where can i find libdbjdbc17.so file . I have downloaded the client from https://wiki.scn.sap.com/wiki/display/SQLANY/SAP+SQL+Anywhere+Database+Client+Download . I dont find that file anywhere ? Any suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: I don't know, I don't use SQL Anywhere nor do I know my way around the SAP support site. I'm just guessing at the normal pattern of libraries, but if the driver requires a native component, then it should be included with your JDBC driver download.